# How do I enable Line In (Microphone is not working)

Tags: windows, drivers, microphone, audio-recording

When I try to input my Microphone, it still doesn't recognize it:
[image: Sound Control Panel]

Tried reinstalling drivers many times, disabling them but still no progress.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that Line-in used to work before. Try set your *Stereo Mix* as your default device and test your Line-in to see if it works.